# Apache - Configuring multiple websites accessed by same IP but different ports

Tags: linux, apache, web, port

I have done this in IIS7.5 with ease.

Say I have a domain mbdev.myftp.biz.

On IIS I have setup sites but each one has a different port.

Example:

```
mbdev.myftp.biz:8004
mbdev.myftp.biz:8006
```

The only thing that is different is the port for the site. Those above URL's got to actual sites on the IIS box.

How can I accomplish the same thing with APACHE? Having the site be on a specific port?

For Example:

```
mbdev.myftp.biz:8600
mbdev.myftp.biz:8601
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache accomplishes this through the VirtualHost directive.  Documentation for version 2.4 can be found on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/index.html and more specifically the configuration directive http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

An example virtualhost config directive pulled from the link above:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
  DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.example.com
  ServerName host.example.com
  ErrorLog logs/host.example.com-error_log
  TransferLog logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks I will check those links out and let you know if I got it to work.

Comment: WOOPS; forgot to enable the site :) Solved